# Run function only once in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react redux project.  I have the below method:

```
const UmvValidator = (actions) => {
    const expiryTime = localStorage.getItem('expiryTime')
    const currentTime = moment().valueOf()
    if (expiryTime) {
        if (expiryTime.valueOf() > currentTime) {
            localStorage.clear('expiryTime')

        }
    } else {
        actions.directToLogin()
    }
}
```

actions.directToLogin() looks like this:

```
export function directToLogin() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(push('/'));
    }
}
```

I want to run this method once, when my component first renders like so:

```
componentWillMount() {
        const { actions } = this.props
         umvValidator(actions)
    }
```

The idea is that if the expiry time is later than the current time, the user will be redirected to the home page.  This sort of works - the user is directed from one page to the home page.  However the home page continues to flicker between the home page and the original page because the umvValidator keeps getting called!

I have no idea to solve this, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
 const UmvValidator = (actions) => {
        const expiryTime = localStorage.getItem('expiryTime');
        const init = localStorage.getItem('init');
        const currentTime = moment().valueOf()
        if (expiryTime && !init) {
            if (expiryTime.valueOf() > currentTime) {
                localStorage.clear('expiryTime')

            }
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('init',1)
            actions.directToLogin()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not normal that your component keep mounting and unmounting. This is where the issues lies. Once you fix this, it will only mount once and your `UmvValidator` function will only be called once.

Because I see route related code in your example, I suspect that your component might be *inside* (a child of) your `router` view element (I don't know what you are using). So each time your component calls actions.directToLogin(), the route changes and a new instance of that same component is created and wakes up again, calling UmvValidator in a loop.

So instead of :

```
<div>
  <routerView>
    <MyComponent/>
    <OtherStuff>
  </routerView>
</div>
```

do:

That's just pseudo code to illustrate what I'm saying.

Another reason could be that you are conditionally rendering your component with a condition that changes a lot and causes the component to mount and unmount:

```
render(){
  return (
       <div>
       {conditionThatChangesALot && <MyComponent/>}
       </div>
  )
}
```

I hope this helps